# Anyone have TestCafe, Firebase and TestCafe Roles working together?

Tags: firebase, testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

TestCafe, Firebase, Roles seem not to work together.

The following TestCafe tests seems to lose the Role state, when using a Firebase-based site. (It uses Google's Firebase demo live site).

I have a much larger, proprietary example, where a basic test works with older versions of Firebase, but simply changing to a newer version causes the test to break (losing state after exiting useRole), so I suspect some kind of incompatibility between TestCafe, Roles, and Firebase, but can't figure out what's going on....

Anyone successful in having recent versions of Firebase and TestCafe working with Roles?

(I also created a github issue here: https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/4939)

`` import { Selector, Role } from 'testcafe';

const ackTerms = Selector('span.mdl-checkbox__tick-outline');
const checkBox = Selector('.mdl-checkbox.is-checked');

const role1 = Role('https://friendly-pix.com/', async t => {
    await t
    .expect(checkBox.count).eql(0)
    .click(ackTerms) 
    .expect(checkBox.count).eql(1)    //on
    .click(ackTerms)
    .expect(checkBox.count).eql(0)    // off
    .click(ackTerms) 
    .expect(checkBox.count).eql(1);    // on, when we exit Role creation.
    // at this point the check box is checked.
}, {preserveUrl: true});

fixture `Friendly Pix test`
    .page `https://friendly-pix.com/`;

test('Roles test', async t => {
    await t
    .wait(5000)   // just let everything settle down.

    .useRole(role1)
    // when useRole is done, the check box should be still checked, however when you get to this breakpoint it will not be.
    .expect(checkBox.count).eql(1)

    // but clicking still works...if you remove the above assertion.
    .click(ackTerms)  //off
    .click(ackTerms); //on
}); ``

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the detailed explanation in [this](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/4939#issuecomment-609744085) comment.